# Django, python-social-auth: Авторизация через соцсеть в desktop приложении

Tags: django

Desktop приложение открывает через браузер сайт, тот выполняет вход при помощи python-social-auth через соцсеть, в итоге сайт отправляет в приложение id пользователя и другую информацию. Как это грамотнее реализовать?

Идея:
Когда пользователь нажимает в десктопном "вход", приложение создаёт на сайте через api новое "логин-обращение" с информацией: идентификатор обращения, ip пользователя, соцсеть. Дальше в браузере сайт получает ид обращения, ставит в нём "начат вход" и перенаправляет на логин страницу соцсети. После входа, в обращении "выполнен вход" становится true, приложение пытается забрать у обращения ид пользователя и другую инфу, если ip соврадают, у него получается, а обращение удаляется.
Если при создании нового обращения у ip уже есть старое, старое удаляется(?).

Comment: restful api - думаю при том, что можно сделать, чтобы авторизация в приложении была без участия браузера. "Как это грамотнее реализовать?" - вы начните реализовывать хоть как-нибудь и/или идею покажите/предложите, а сообщество уже поможет.

Comment: Когда пользователь нажимает в десктопном "вход", приложение создаёт на сайте через api новое "логин-обращение" с информацией: идентификатор обращения, ip пользователя, соцсеть, выполнен ли вход. Дальше в браузере сайт получает ид обращения и перенаправляет на логин страницу соцсети. После входа, в обращении "выполнен вход" становится true, приложение забирает у обращения ид пользователя и другую инфу, если ip соврадают. Обращение удаляется.